# PANDA SQLITE Times series Plotting

Tags: python, pandas

I got a question (i tried differents solutions for 2 hours without success) regarding Plotting series from Sqlite.

My SQL statement :

```
p2 = sql.read_sql('select PCE,DT, VALUE_DEMANDE - VALUE_FORCAST as FC_ERROR FROM PCE GROUP BY PCE,DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST', cnx)
```

The result OK :

```
       PCE    DT                   FC_ERROR
0      TAG1   01/01/2015 00:00      3.573
1      TAG1   01/01/2015 01:00      3.514
..............................................
2      TAG2   01/01/2015 00:00      2.573
3      TAG2   01/01/2015 01:00      1.514
..............................................
2      TAG3   01/01/2015 00:00      6.573
3      TAG3   01/01/2015 01:00      4.514
```

I want to get line plotting (x axis : DT) as the second chart in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html
I try with :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Error' :p2['FC_ERROR']},columns=list({'TAG1','TAG2','TAG3'}))
df.index = p2['DT']
ax=df.plot(lw=0.5,colormap='jet',marker='+',markersize=2,title='Time series Previsions / Reel')
ax=set_xlabel("Periode")
ax=set_ylabel("Value en Gwh")
```

How can i  generated columns=list from data in the same column ?
Should I make pd.series(...

Thanks

## MODIFICATION

ok guys i try

```
  p2 = sql.read_sql('select PCE,DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST, VALUE_DEMANDE,VALUE_FORCAST ,VALUE_DEMANDE - VALUE_FORCAST as FC_ERROR FROM PCE', cnx)  

 for name, groupe in p2.groupby('PCE'):
        print name 

 df = pd.DataFrame({'Pce' : groupe['PCE'].values,'FE' :groupe['FC_ERROR'].values})
    df.index = groupe['DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST']

    df = pd.DataFrame(groupe['FC_ERROR'].values, index=groupe['DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST'], columns=set(name))
    plt.figure()
    df.plot()
```

the 'for name ' loop is working (and faster than set i think) i got (demo) 2 string element.
When I launch the script python told me :

```
for name, groupe in p2.groupby('PCE'):
    print name 



df = pd.DataFrame({'Pce' : groupe['PCE'].values,'FE' :groupe['FC_ERROR'].values})
df.index = groupe['DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST']

df = pd.DataFrame(groupe['FC_ERROR'].values, index=groupe['DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST'], columns=set(name))
plt.figure()
df.plot()
A12250I2
A12250T2
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-138-73fb44bbbf67>", line 9, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(groupe['FC_ERROR'].values, index=groupe['DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST'], columns=set(name))

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 239, in __init__
    copy=copy)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 399, in _init_ndarray
    return create_block_manager_from_blocks([values.T], [columns, index])

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3534, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3515, in construction_error
    passed,implied))

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 22509), indices imply (6, 22509)
```

I am stuck, if someone can give me a hint ?

---

The following script plot each dataframe (from the loop) on a plot.

```
for name, groupe in p2.groupby('PCE'):
    df = pd.DataFrame({str(name) : groupe['FC_ERROR'].values}) 
    df.index=groupe['DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST']
    df.plot()
```

I would like to plot all dataframe on 1 chart ! Do you have a hint ?

Comment: I do not really understand your question, maybe you could elaborate? The closest thing I can think you would want is the DataFrame.T attribute, which is the transposed version of the dataframe.

Comment: You first have to convert the strings to real datetimes: `df.index = pd.to_datetime(p2['DT'])`

Comment: Thanks for yours responses; I just want to plot the values (FC_ERROR) for TAG1 and TAG2 with lines on DT (dates) axis. It might be trivial for you but not for me ;-(

Comment: `set(name)` gives you a set of all individual characters, while you want a single string here (try it out yourself to see the result)

Comment: Do `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` before the loop, and `df.plot(ax=ax)` in the loop

Comment: Thank you very much . I spent lot's of time in this question but I increase my knowledge of panda/python .....;-).  Thank again joris